# Expo-Camera, takePictureAsync undefined (Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: ref.current.takePictureAsync is not a function)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, use-ref, expo-camera

I'm trying to create react app with expo using expo-camera for taking pictures. I have separately components `MeasurementCameraScreen` and `MeasurementCamera`. I'm using `useRef()` hook to be able to call `takePictureAsync()` from the `MeasuremenCameraScreen`.

When pressing the take image -button takePicture() console.logs the `ref`, so I assume the onPress gets there, but then I get the following error message:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: ref.current.takePictureAsync is not a function. (In 'ref.current.takePictureAsync(options)', 'ref.current.takePictureAsync' is undefined)]
```

I saw that people have also had same issues with takePictureAcync(), but I haven't found solution to my problem. I also tired to combine the `MeasurementCameraScreen` and `MeasurementCamera` components to one component, and with that I got the camera working, but I'm curious of why it doesn't work now? `refs` are new thing for me so I think there is something wrong with them.

Here are the components:

**`MeasurementCameraScreen`**

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'

import MeasurementCamera from '../components/MeasurementCamera'
import Text from '../components/Text'

const MeasurementCameraScreen = () => {
    const cameraRef = useRef(null)

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
                <MeasurementCamera ref={cameraRef}/>
            </View>
            <View>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => cameraRef.current.takePicture()}
                style={styles.buttonContainer}
            >
                <Text>
                    Take image
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    cameraContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'flex-end'
    },
})

export default MeasurementCameraScreen
```

**`MeasurementCamera`**

```
import { useState, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native"
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera'

import Text from './Text'

const MeasurementCamera = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const getPermission = async () => {
            const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
            setHasPermission(status === 'granted')
        }
        getPermission()

    }, [])

    const takePicture = async () => {
        if (ref) {
            console.log(ref.current)
            const options = {
                quality: 1,
                base64: true
            }
            const picture = await ref.current.takePictureAsync(options)
            console.log(picture.uri)
        }
    }

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        takePicture
    }))

    if (hasPermission === null) {
        return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>
    } if (hasPermission === false) {
        return <Text>No access to camera</Text>
    }

    return (
       <Camera
            ref={ref}
            style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
        />
    )
})

MeasurementCamera.displayName = 'MeasurementCamera'

export default MeasurementCamera
```

Comment: The error basically means that `ref.current` is undefined. Don't worry about takePictureAsync for now, you need to fix the ref part. console.log() stuff to debug this.

Comment: @ChrisG with console.log(ref) I get `Object {
  "current": Object {
    "takePicture": [Function _callee2],
  },
}`

before the error

Comment: That looks like the camera object has a takePicture function but no takePictureAsync function

Comment: @ChrisG Tried it and got `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.` error. In expo documentation there is only takePictureAsync function, no takePicture function

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/

Comment: I'll add an example and please tell me if it's work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the solution!

After reading the [medium](https://kyle-buntin.medium.com/getting-started-with-camera-in-react-native-5a06302a58df) article @LouaySleman recommended about the expo-camera I understood that to be able to use the `Expo Camera` components functions I need to use `ref`. So what I needed was **two refs**, **one** for the components to communicate and **another one** to be able to use the `Camera` `takePictureAsync()` function.

> Now that we have permissions to access the Camera, you should get familiar with the ref props on line 132, in the Camera component. There we have passed the cameraRef that was previously defined with useRef. In doing so, we will have access to interesting methods that we can call to control the Camera.

Answer (score 3):

What you needed is to add two refs, one for the components to `communicate` and another one to be able to use the Camera `takePictureAsync()` function Please check this example from [medium](https://kyle-buntin.medium.com/getting-started-with-camera-in-react-native-5a06302a58df):

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import {
 View,
 Text,
 TouchableOpacity,
 SafeAreaView,
 StyleSheet,
 Dimensions,
} from "react-native";
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import { Video } from "expo-av";
export default function CameraScreen() {
 const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
 const [cameraType, setCameraType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
 const [isPreview, setIsPreview] = useState(false);
 const [isCameraReady, setIsCameraReady] = useState(false);
 const [isVideoRecording, setIsVideoRecording] = useState(false);
 const [videoSource, setVideoSource] = useState(null);
 const cameraRef = useRef();
 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
 const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
 setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })();
  }, []);
 const onCameraReady = () => {
 setIsCameraReady(true);
  };
 const takePicture = async () => {
 if (cameraRef.current) {
 const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true, skipProcessing: true };
 const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
 const source = data.uri;
 if (source) {
 await cameraRef.current.pausePreview();
 setIsPreview(true);
 console.log("picture", source);
      }
    }
  };
 const recordVideo = async () => {
 if (cameraRef.current) {
 try {
 const videoRecordPromise = cameraRef.current.recordAsync();
 if (videoRecordPromise) {
 setIsVideoRecording(true);
 const data = await videoRecordPromise;
 const source = data.uri;
 if (source) {
 setIsPreview(true);
 console.log("video source", source);
 setVideoSource(source);
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
 console.warn(error);
      }
    }
  };
 const stopVideoRecording = () => {
 if (cameraRef.current) {
 setIsPreview(false);
 setIsVideoRecording(false);
 cameraRef.current.stopRecording();
    }
  };
 const switchCamera = () => {
 if (isPreview) {
 return;
    }
 setCameraType((prevCameraType) =>
 prevCameraType === Camera.Constants.Type.back
        ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
        : Camera.Constants.Type.back
    );
  };
 const cancelPreview = async () => {
 await cameraRef.current.resumePreview();
 setIsPreview(false);
 setVideoSource(null);
  };
 const renderCancelPreviewButton = () => (
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={cancelPreview} style={styles.closeButton}>
 <View style={[styles.closeCross, { transform: [{ rotate: "45deg" }] }]} />
 <View
 style={[styles.closeCross, { transform: [{ rotate: "-45deg" }] }]}
 />
 </TouchableOpacity>
  );
 const renderVideoPlayer = () => (
 <Video
 source={{ uri: videoSource }}
 shouldPlay={true}
 style={styles.media}
 />
  );
 const renderVideoRecordIndicator = () => (
 <View style={styles.recordIndicatorContainer}>
 <View style={styles.recordDot} />
 <Text style={styles.recordTitle}>{"Recording..."}</Text>
 </View>
  );
 const renderCaptureControl = () => (
 <View style={styles.control}>
 <TouchableOpacity disabled={!isCameraReady} onPress={switchCamera}>
 <Text style={styles.text}>{"Flip"}</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
 <TouchableOpacity
 activeOpacity={0.7}
 disabled={!isCameraReady}
 onLongPress={recordVideo}
 onPressOut={stopVideoRecording}
 onPress={takePicture}
 style={styles.capture}
 />
 </View>
  );
 if (hasPermission === null) {
 return <View />;
  }
 if (hasPermission === false) {
 return <Text style={styles.text}>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
 return (
 <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
 <Camera
 ref={cameraRef}
 style={styles.container}
 type={cameraType}
 flashMode={Camera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
 onCameraReady={onCameraReady}
 onMountError={(error) => {
 console.log("camera error", error);
        }}
 />
 <View style={styles.container}>
 {isVideoRecording && renderVideoRecordIndicator()}
 {videoSource && renderVideoPlayer()}
 {isPreview && renderCancelPreviewButton()}
 {!videoSource && !isPreview && renderCaptureControl()}
 </View>
 </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;
const closeButtonSize = Math.floor(WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.032);
const captureSize = Math.floor(WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.09);
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
 closeButton: {
 position: "absolute",
 top: 35,
 left: 15,
 height: closeButtonSize,
 width: closeButtonSize,
 borderRadius: Math.floor(closeButtonSize / 2),
 justifyContent: "center",
 alignItems: "center",
 backgroundColor: "#c4c5c4",
 opacity: 0.7,
 zIndex: 2,
  },
 media: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
 closeCross: {
 width: "68%",
 height: 1,
 backgroundColor: "black",
  },
 control: {
 position: "absolute",
 flexDirection: "row",
 bottom: 38,
 width: "100%",
 alignItems: "center",
 justifyContent: "center",
  },
 capture: {
 backgroundColor: "#f5f6f5",
 borderRadius: 5,
 height: captureSize,
 width: captureSize,
 borderRadius: Math.floor(captureSize / 2),
 marginHorizontal: 31,
  },
 recordIndicatorContainer: {
 flexDirection: "row",
 position: "absolute",
 top: 25,
 alignSelf: "center",
 justifyContent: "center",
 alignItems: "center",
 backgroundColor: "transparent",
 opacity: 0.7,
  },
 recordTitle: {
 fontSize: 14,
 color: "#ffffff",
 textAlign: "center",
  },
 recordDot: {
 borderRadius: 3,
 height: 6,
 width: 6,
 backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
 marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
 text: {
 color: "#fff",
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks @LouaySleman the article helped me to find the solution!

Comment: You're welcome :D, can you mark it as a correct answer and upvote it if you like :D

Comment: That's just a wall of code. Please add what the specific problem was and how it was solved.

Comment: This example worked perfectly, Just copy and paste > done